# How to Add io2d.h library to intellisense in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

So I have this C++ Project which uses the io2d library.

I installed the library and compile and run the project with CMake.

However Intellisense Show Errors in the cpp Files which use  like this:

[image]

I thought if I add the path of the header in the `c_cpp_properties.json` it would work:

[image]

However no luck. What else can I check.

I'm on Ubuntu. Visual Studio Code Version 1.44.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

io2d header uses the cairo library internally. In order to get this to work we need to add the include path for cairo aswell:

```
    "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "/usr/local/include/io2d",
        "/usr/include/cairo"
    ],
```